# Redirect after login angular

Tags: angular, authentication

I want to make a redirect after login. I used a `this.router.navigate` methode like in the photo below ,

```
  loginer(act:String) {
if (this.log.valid) {

  for (var i = 0; i < this.validtab.length; i++) {
    if (this.validtab[i].username == this.log.value.username && this.validtab[i].password == this.log.value.password) {
       this.connected=true
        this.onchange.emit(this.connected)
        this.router.navigate(['/Home']) 
        this._snackBar.open("Bienvenu", 'Home Page', {
          duration: 2000,
        });
    
    }else this.connected=false
   
  }

}
```

}

But an error displayed to me in the console and i can't fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNREk.png)

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LoginComponent -> LoginComponent -> LoginComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginComponent!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LoginComponent -> LoginComponent -> LoginComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginComponent!
```

App.module.ts

[App.module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNREk.png)

Loign.service.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mx8W.png)

Comment: Try to provide a more complete and functional example; for instance, in this case it could be related to how you declare the component that performs these actions.

Comment: `LoginComponent -> LoginComponent -> LoginComponent` looks very suspicious to me, though.. are you attempting to inject LoginComponent into itself?

Comment: Please add module.ts and LoginComponent.ts

Comment: @JanithaRasanga Deal